# Windows Phone 8.1: Change background on phone theme change (Application.Current.Resources is empty)

Tags: c#, themes, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to detect theme change in my application so I can change the background image accordingly.
Sadly the WP7 example that included

```
(Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] ==
Visibility.Visible
```

throws an exception saying:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code WinRT
>   information:   
> Cannot find a resource with the given key.   
> Additional
>   information: Unspecified error

On debugging it turns out that Application.Current.Resources has 0 elements.

I would be very happy if it would turn out that I messed up something, but on running the WP7 example (in a WP8.1 project) found here: [How to apply theme resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it resulted in the same exception as before.   
Does anyone know a WP8.1 solution to my problem? :)

*Additional info:*   
I tried using the above mentioned code in the OnNavigatedTo part, the page constructor and even tried using it in a button click, but they all yielded the same result.   
Other things like the font colour actually change after changing the theme of the phone automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code if you are using windows phone 8.1(not windows phone 8.1 silverlight)

```
if (App.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark)
       {}
```

hope this helps